# Integrating along a contour - Simple Example - Point out the error

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to integrate $1+2z$ along: $\gamma : z = t + i(t-1) \ : 1 \leq t \leq 2$

I find that $dz/dt=1+i$, therefore:

$$\int_1^2 dt \ 1+2(t+i(t-1))(1+i)$$

I may very well be making a mistake this very next step (taking 1 out):

$$1 + \int_1^2 dt \ 2(t+i(t-1))(1+i)$$

$$1 + \int_1^2 dt \ 2t + 2it + 2i(t-1) - 2(t-1)$$

Now, $2t-2(t-1) = 2$, so

$$1 + \int_1^2 dt \  2 +2i\int_1^2 dt \ 2t -1$$

I think the above step is incorrect, I cannot take out $2i$ like that and still perform the integration, right?

and then I have

$$1+2+4i = 3+4i$$
Which is not correct.

Please do not provide me with the solution, nor a way of doing this more neatly. I need to know where is the mistake, and please tell me why that is a mistake so that I do not make it again.

Comment: u miss a factor of two in fron of $2 i t$ by going fromline three to four

Comment: are you counting the lines beginning with the first \$$$$ ?

Comment: Yep................................!

Comment: not sure where that factor of 2 should come from there